# AngularJS - Can't access promise's then() function

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I am using a promise in one of my app's services in order to manage the access to a certain variable. Specifically, when a certain directive is compiled, it calls that service's function to [initialise a leaflet map](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-l.map). However, since there are some few controllers trying to access other of that service's functions even before the map is initialised, I thought of using a deferred object, in order to setup those calls as callbacks after the initialisation. See the service's code:

```
function mapService(leaflet, $q) {
    var map;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promisedMap = deferred.promise;

    var exports = {
        initializeMap : initializeMap,
        getMap : getMap
    };
    return exports;

    //myMapDirective calls this on its link function
    function initializeMap(mapElement) {
        map = leaflet.map(mapElement, {...});

        deferred.resolve(map);
    }

    function getMap() {
        return promisedMap;
    }
}
```

My idea was to access the map object using the `getMap` function, like so:

`mapService.getMap().then(doStuffWithMap);`

However, in the following test (`mocha`, `chai`, `chai-as-promised`):

```
describe('mapService', function () {
    var deferred, promisedData;

    beforeEach(function () {
        bard.inject(...);

        deferred = $q.defer();
        promisedData = deferred.promise;

        //$compile map directive, and etc
        element = angular.element('<my-map></my-map>');
        compiledElem = $compile(element)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
    });

    it('should have initialised map', function() {
        mapService.getMap().
        then(function(map) {
           deferred.resolve(map);
        });
        $rootScope.$apply();

        return promisedData.should.become(someMockMapObj);
    });
}
```

I get `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.$eval(expr)')` because of the `then()` call.

With some basic `console.log` debugging I found that `promisedMap` has, indeed, the `then` method defined, leading me to the conclusion that it is a valid promise object. I am not sure that the directive is being compiled, though, even though I am doing exactly what I have done with another test suite (which is working just fine). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm honstly not sure why you are having issues with it.  I've set up a plunk using the same concepts and it seems to work just fine.

http://plnkr.co/edit/flolyGtOIc7gsQ6v7pzU?p=preview

```
app.service('testService', ['$q', function($q){

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promisedMap = deferred.promise;

    function initialize() {
        deferred.resolve('Test message.');
    }

    function getMessage() {
        return promisedMap;
    }

    var exports = {
        getMessage : getMessage,
        initialize: initialize
    };

   return exports;

}]);

app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', 'testService', function($scope, testService) {

    $scope.init = function() {
      testService.getMessage().then(function(msg){
        alert(msg);
      });

      setTimeout(function(){
        testService.initialize();
      }, 1000);
    }

}]);
```

@John Kim - You can definitely return a promise before it is resolved. That is the whole point.